# Zip dependency in Gradle

Tags: gradle, zip

I have 2 modules:

- `transfer-application`
- `transfer-executable`

I need to package `transfer-executable` as `zip` and add it as dependency to `transfer-application` like this:

```
dependencies {
     zip project(':transfer-executable')
}
```

I want that zip be available in classpath. Does Gradle provide such functionality using native api. If not, what library I need to use?

If you can, please provide an example of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    def execBuildDir = project(':transfer-executable').buildDir
    runtime fileTree(dir: "$execBuildDir/distributions", include: '*.zip')
}
```

Check it works:

```
> jar tf transfer-application/build/libs/transfer-application-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep zip

BOOT-INF/lib/transfer-executable-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
BOOT-INF/lib/spring-cloud-starter-zipkin-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/zipkin-sender-kafka11-2.7.14.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/zipkin-sender-amqp-client-2.7.14.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/zipkin-reporter-2.7.14.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/zipkin-2.12.0.jar
```